# The AppLovin' nightmare in Xcode, impossible to build the project

Tags: c#, ios, xcode

it's been weeks that I'm blocked because I can't build my project in Xcode on iOS. I looked all over the internet, none of the suggestions worked for me. I really hope I'm not a rare exception because this problem is painful and prevents me from moving forward..

Here is a the error that i have in Xcode

> "#import <AppLovinSDK/AppLovinSDK.h' file not found"

Comment: How have you installed the AppLovin SDK?

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the reply. The SDK was installed by a person from AppLovin

Comment: That isn't really an answer. Surely they didn't modify your Xcode project on your Mac? You need to integrate their SDK with your project somehow, using their cocoapod, for example. The error message says that you haven't done that so the .h file can't be found. Even if someone from AppLovin did modify your project to integrate the API you probably need to actually run some command to complete the task, especially if you have pulled the project from a source code repository

Comment: I can guarantee that nobody modified the Xcode project on my mac because I bought it recently, then I simply transferred the project from an old pc to the Macbook in order to build it and publish it from the Macbook to the App Store

Comment: Right, so you need to understand how the SDK is integrated with your project and redo that integration. It could be as simple as running `pod update`

Comment: I will try to do that, thank you for you help!

Comment: I'm still in this nightmare.. I really don't know what to do anymore, i tried everything

Comment: Surely there are instructions on the applovin site on adding their framework to iOS projects?

Comment: I redid the integration of AppLovin in the project, following the official documentation, and I still have this problem... It drives me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Try to Build from Unity and not Build and Run:

[image]

And then open the `.xworkspace` file and not the `.xcodeproj` file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered it yesterday. If ApplovinSDK in Podfile is added implicitly, try to make it explicit. The problem was solved in my case.

I describe the detail..
There was no AppLovinSDK in the Podfile.
The Podfile had "GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin" instead.
ApplovinSDK  will be installed from it.
I tried to add ApplovinSDK in Podfile ahead of "GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin"
Then it works.
like this...

```
 pod 'ApplovinSDK', '10.3.6'     --- Added. 
 pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin', '10.3.6.0'
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, what do you mean by explicit ? I'm sorry i don't understand, however, by updating google mobile ads in the terminal, it fixed the error with AppLovinSDK.h' file not found, but instead i have other errors, these are the warnings i have in the terminal after i've updated google ads: "- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target." and i don't know the meaning of this, but i now have a workspace file, and i have other erros when i try to build the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't work for me... I want to cry